# Why are my vertex normals rotating as the camera rotates?

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

The vertex normals of my teapot are not transforming as expected. My suspicions are that the normal matrix is not transforming in the right co-ordinate space. I would like to understand more about the problem and how it could be resolved.

Below are links to images to demonstrate the problem and also the GLSL source code I am using to draw the vertex normals.

The teapot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgMac.png

The teapot up close: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCArn.png

When I rotate the camera the circled vertex normal rotates too: http://imgur.com/6laONRj.png

vertex.glsl:

```
attribute vec3 v_Position;        /* vertex position in model space */
attribute vec3 v_Normal;          /* vertex normal vector in model space */

uniform mat4 v_ModelViewMatrix;   /* model space to world space to eye space transform */
uniform mat4 v_ProjectionMatrix;  /* eye space to clip space transform */

out VS_OUT {
        vec3 normal;              /* vertex normal in eye space. */
} vs_out;

void main(void)
{
        vec4 WorldPosition = v_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(v_Position.xyz, 1.0);

        /* I know it's bad to compute this on the GPU but I wanted to be sure my matrix routines were not to blame. */
        mat3 NormalMatrix = transpose(inverse(mat3(v_ModelViewMatrix)));

        vs_out.normal = normalize(NormalMatrix * v_Normal);
        gl_Position = v_ProjectionMatrix * WorldPosition;
}
```

geometry.glsl

```
layout(triangles) in;
layout(line_strip, max_vertices = 2) out;

in VS_OUT {
        vec3 normal;
} gs_in[];

void main(void)
{
        gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
        EmitVertex();

        gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + 0.1 * vec4(gs_in[0].normal, 0.0);
        EmitVertex();

        EndPrimitive();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in your geometry shader, gl_in[0].gl_Position is in clip space, while gs_in[0].normal is in eye space. You probably want to do the projection in the geometry shader.

Comment: Yet another reason to have variable names to state the space of the value.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much for your help.